# iOS: Handling overlapping background requests

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, background, thread-safety

In an iOS app, I'm writing a class that will be messaged, go do a background request (via `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`), and then return the result through a delegate method (that will then be displayed on a map). Everything seems to work right when one request is happening at a time, but I'm trying to figure out how to handle multiple overlapping requests. For example, if a user enters something in a search box that starts a background thread, and then enters something else before the initial background thread completes, how should this be handled?

There are a few options (don't let the second request start while the first is in progress, stop the first as soon as the second is requested, let both run simultaneously and return independent results, etc.), but is there a common/recommended way to deal with this?

Comment: I should read that in more detail (the link in your comment is wrong, by the way). But my question is more about how to handle this particular situation, not the specifics of actually implementing it using dispatch queues, `NSOperation`s, etc.

Comment: Whoops, here's [the correct link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's universal answer to this. My suggestion is to separate tasks (in form of NSOperations and/or blocks) by their function and relationships between them.

Example: you don't want add image resizing operation to the same queue with fetching some unrelated feed from web, especially if no relationship between them exists. Or maybe you do because both require great amount of memory and because of that can't run in parallel.

But you'd probably want to add web image search operations to same queue while canceling operations of the same type added to this queue before. Each of those image search operations might init image resize operation and place it into some other queue. Now you have an relationship and have to cancel resizing in addition to image search operation. What if image search operation takes longer than associated resize operation? How do you keep a reference to it or know when it's done?

Yeah, it gets complicated easily and sorry if I didn't give you any concrete answers because of uniqueness of each situation but making it run like a Swiss clock in the end is very satisfying :)